# flex2gateway problem

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion

I have a test server which has been working up until recently. Its running ColdFusion 8

But now when I browse from the server or externally

http://localhost/flex2gateway

I get the following error

500 
No configured channel has an endpoint path '/flex2gateway/eurl.axd/f902379d5cc8514ba3feca5933aee37d'

javax.servlet.ServletException: No configured channel has an endpoint path '/flex2gateway/eurl.axd/f902379d5cc8514ba3feca5933aee37d'.
    at coldfusion.filter.FlashRequestControlFilter.doFilter(FlashRequestControlFilter.java:87)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)

This may or may not relate to us having recently installed and modified some IIS settings.

---

Everything is working ok, except for the flex2gateway. IIS & CF all talk properly. I managed to get it to work by setting ASP.NET to 2.0 and creating an empty web.config file. Setting it to ASP.NET 4 however still has the same issue, must be missing a configuration somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the web.config files that .NET 2.0 were pointing to in the IIS configuration were missing.

Adding empty web.config files fixed this problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>

  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you recently installed IIS; are you sure that IIS and CF8 are set up to "Talk" to each other?  There is a tool that comes with CF called the Web Server Configuration tool.  You can use it to tell your IIS Instance to send CF related requests to your instance of CF8.  If you are using CF Standard you can only have one instance of CF8.

Since your URL specifies 127.0.0.1 you may also have issues with virtual hosts.  Do you have multiple instances of IIS?  If so, how does IIS know which one to send 127.0.0.1 to?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your **crossdomain.xml**?